# C# Simple GUI Panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've been stuck in a simple problem. and i could not remove it.

I have changed the Panel to static public. to access the panel across the pages. and when ever i changed the GUI it resets the static public to public. and gives me an error. that you can't access the public member here.

So i have to set static every time when ever i change a bit of a GUI to run the program.

Could you please assist me.

I know this is a rubbish question. I am curious to know that what is happening at backhand.

I am using visual studio 2011. developer preview.

Comment: What it the goal of such manipulation?

Comment: What GUI library are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? Metro?

Comment: the goal is to use the some resources of one form to another form. with no globally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using WinForms.

Don't change the automatically generated code generated by Microsoft Visual Studio, it will just be overwritten when you change something. Instead use a `static` in the code behind.

For example a button that changes a variable when clicked.

```
public static int MyGlobalVariable
private void button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyGlobalVariable = 4;
}
```

Also consider a completely different design as using public statics sooner or later will cause a lot of headache for you. Usually sooner.

Comment: static public System.Windows.Forms.Panel Program; this is what i am declaring

Comment: yeah, got that. You are using this form another place since it needs to be static - How does that code look like? Edit your question please.

Comment: Thanks. i have a another way to do this. but i want to do this in this very way. hope u understand what i trying to do. Actually i am trying to use panel declared in one form to another form easily. i do not want to make a function or pass referance of the panel object. just just want to use in a normal way. so just need to know what is the background changes the visual studio is trying to make. should. Also want to know, is this a good way.

Comment: this is not the easy way to do it, but please edit your question and include the code that uses this static variable. Otherwise I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question correctly (what do you mean by "when ever i changed the GUI"?) but perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Panel panelS = new Panel();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1.panelS.Location = new Point(100, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: in the Form2's constructor you have no reference to Form1 and instantiating it in Form2's constructor would defeat the purpose. You would need to pass a reference of Form1 into Form2..